# Python. Plot histogram of times

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataFrame with datetime column.

For example:

```
0       2017-11-01 07:00:33
1       2017-11-01 08:00:39
2       2017-11-01 09:00:53
3       2017-11-02 07:00:53
4       2017-11-02 08:00:59
5       2017-11-02 10:01:10
6       2017-11-03 07:01:15
7       2017-11-03 10:01:27
8       2017-11-03 11:01:28
```

I need to plot hist of times (not dates and times)

I've tried to create column of times and use Grouper but that's not worked.

```
df['time']=df['datetime'].dt.time
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='10M')).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double `groupby`, also for `10 Minutes` frequency use `10T`, `10M` is `10 end month frequency`:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='10T')).size()

s = df.groupby(df.index.time).sum()

s.plot()
```